# how to tell if a popup has fully loaded

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to tell from a parent window if a popup window has fully loaded?

```
<body>
  <div id="btn">display web page</div>
    <div id="somediv">
    </div>
  </body>
```

I write the following script to determine if the pop up is already loaded, but it does not work.

```
<script>
 $("#somediv")[0].onload = function(){
            alert('loaded');
            console.log("rr");
        };
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use $("#somediv").load(function(){}) ? Also, what do you mean by fully loaded ? Because since the HTML is loaded, your empty div is also fully loaded

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
<body>
  <div id="btn">display web page</div>
  <div id="somediv">
  </div>
</body>

$("#somediv").load("a.html", function(){
    alert('loaded');
    console.log("rr");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jboo92k4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var winPop;

            function OpenWindow() {
                winPop = window.open("popupwin.html");
                CheckWinStatus();
            }

            function CheckWinStatus() {
                try {
                    asdf = winPop.document.body;
                    WindowLoaded();
                }
                catch(e) {
                    setTimeout("CheckWinStatus()",1000);
                }
            }

            function WindowLoaded() {
                alert(winPop.document.title);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="Form1">
            <input type="button" name="B1" value="Open" onclick="OpenWindow()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

- The function `OpenWindow()` is called when button `b1` is clicked.
- Inside `OpenWindow()`, a popup window `popupwin.html` is made to open.
- `CheckWinStatus()` checks whether the popup has fully loaded or not. It has a timeout value of 1000 ms.
- When the popup window has fully loaded, `WindowLoaded()` is called. This is where you would perform your popup dependent action.